# Does any runtime scanning exist with ASP.NET Core (not covered by unit tests), to prepopulate ELMAH?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, elmah, health-monitoring, asp-net-config-builders

I'm a solo developer who has a big ASP Core site acting as a complex blog mind map.

I need help with creating a basics checklist and a way to ensure that everything is running, aside from unit tests. Examples include

- Following links (Razor page moved to a new location, and the Classname doesn't match folder/namespace)
- functionality of workarounds (./well-known working?)
- quirks regarding ASP.NET Config which could be validated at runtime (per environment)
- other checksum() validation such as /healthcheck /status /load /opsapproval /iscorrectenvironment
- fetching service dependency and availability or maintenance windows (planned or notify)

in this I could add special directions for common environment-based deployment considerations (if..then edit hosts file AND have VPN2 connected, or email Josh)

Comment: Some of this can be done through the front-end using Selenium.  (It automates the browser.)

Comment: What I do is I have a method in my program.cs that collects all this information and logs it into Seq Server.